# ValueError: The shape invariant specified for ones_1:0 is not compatible with the initial shape of the loop variable

Tags: tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
z = tf.ones((1, 3))

out = tf.ones((1, 3))
print('out:', out)
i = tf.constant(0)

def cond(i, _):
    return i < 10


def body(i, out):
    i = i + 1
    out = tf.concat([out, out], axis=0)
    return [i, out]

_, out = tf.while_loop(cond, body, [i, out], shape_invariants=[i.get_shape(), tf.TensorShape([None])])

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
res = sess.run([_, out])
print(res)
```

I hope print ([[1, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1]] ....)
shape = (10, 3)

but print"ValueError: The shape invariant specified for ones_1:0 is not compatible with the initial shape of the loop variable. It enters the loop with shape (1, 3), but the specified shape invariant is (?,)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get a shape [10, 3], you would get a shape [2**n, 3], n is the value in the cond() function (i < n).

```
import tensorflow as tf

out = tf.ones((1, 3))

i = tf.constant(0)


def cond(i, _):
    i += 1
    return i < 4


def body(i, out):
    i = i + 1
    out = tf.concat([out, out], axis=0)
    return i, out

_, out = tf.while_loop(cond, body, [i, out], shape_invariants=[i.get_shape(), tf.TensorShape([None, 3])])

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
_, res = sess.run([_, out])
print(res)
print(res.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change to follow code.

```
_, out = tf.while_loop(cond, body, [i, out], shape_invariants=[i.get_shape(), tf.TensorShape([None,3])])
```

**Edit**

The above code is used to solve the error. If you want to output (10,3), you should modify `body()`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
z = tf.ones((1, 3))

out = tf.ones((1, 3))
print('out:', out)
i = tf.constant(0)

def cond(i, _):
    return i < 9

def body(i, new_out):
    i = i + 1
    new_out = tf.concat([new_out, out], axis=0)
    return [i, new_out]

_, out = tf.while_loop(cond, body, [i, out], shape_invariants=[i.get_shape(), tf.TensorShape([None,3])])

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
res = sess.run([_, out])
print(res[1].shape)

# print
(10, 3)
```